# How to use HTML5 cache with MVC applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, caching

I'm having a problem trying to do something that should be very simple ( show an offline page when the user does not have Internet access).
I have an MVC application that loads on my address `http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/`

I added a manifest.cache file to the web site with the following content:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 11-04-2013

CACHE:
/MobilePortal/

NETWORK:

FALLBACK:
/MobilePortal/ /MobilePortal/offline.html
```

The idea behind this is to show an offline.html page when the user does not have internet access.

On my application MasterPage I included:

```
<html manifest="<%=Url.Content("~/manifest.cache") %>"">
```

When I access the application with Internet connection with Chrome I get the following through the console:

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/manifest.cache 192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Checking event 192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Downloading event 192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 2) http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/offline.html      192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Progress event (1 of 2) http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/ 192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Progress event (2 of 2)  192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Cached event
```

I think everything is fine here.

I then turn off my Internet connection and access the `http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/` URL
but the offline.html page is not shown.
Instead I get this on the Chrome console:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest     http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/manifest.cache 192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Checking event 192.168.2.29:1
Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (-1) http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/manifest.cache 192.168.2.29:1
```

Am I missing something with the fallback rules? I tried adding a index.html file to the application and included the following fallback rule:

```
FALLBACK:
/MobilePortal/index.html /MobilePortal/offline.html
```

When I tried to access `http://192.168.2.29/MobilePortal/index.html` the browser showed the offline.html page with success.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In general avoid URLs which are also patterns.  In the `CACHE` section `/MobilePortal/` is a specific page, but in the `FALLBACK` section it is a pattern, which will match any URL that starts `/MobilePortal/` like `/MobilePortal/index.html` or `/MobilePortal/UrlThatIMadeUp`.  The approach you've taken [tends to cause issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15823748/8655) because `/MobilePortal/` is cached (because it references the manifest) but you're also trying to have it fallback.

Comment: Should I take the `/MobilePortal/` from the `CACHE` section then? The behaviour you mentioned on the `FALLBACK` section is what I want. For any URL that starts with `/MobilePortal/` I want to show the offline.html page if the user does not have Internet access.

Comment: There's no point taking it from the `CACHE` section, if the page at that URL references the manifest, it will be cached anyway.  You need to re-think your approach here.